# Android app's Achievements view doesn't show +2's from tag wiki edit approvals

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, android-app, api

I just noticed a bug in the Android app v1.0.51: reputation events from tag wiki edit suggestions aren't shown in the Achievements list on the Android app. This is from a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

The following screenshots were taken within a minute of each other.

## Website achievements list: some +2's

> [image: I have two tag wiki suggested edit approvals in this screenshot]

## Android app: they don't show up

> [image: same reputation events, but the tag wiki suggested edit approvals are missing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed (with a new version of the API, not an update of the Android app itself). From the What's New section of the [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8):

> All your reputation changes are in the achievements popup, not just ones related to posts. I actually added this in the API, so you probably already saw it, but this is the only spot where I get to say what's new.

[image]