# Can't see reputation change for approved tag excerpts in app

Tags: bug, reputation, ios-app, tag-wiki-excerpt

Web achievements dialog looks like this:

> [image: web]

iOS app doesn't show it (same for android app):

> [image: ios]

Approved excerpts: [one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/151992), [two](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/151989).

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: This is [already reported for the android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243195/android-apps-achievements-view-doesnt-show-2s-from-tag-wiki-edit-approvals)